# load hidden tab image after select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, tabs

i use idtabs js for make tab in main page .

```
http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/
```

i put each tab 12 images . when page load first load tab div and header and menu images not load first . so 4min waiting to page load complete .

i want in load page first main images load then defult tab load images and when i select other tabs image on tab loaded ???

```
<div id="tabs" dir="rtl">
<ul class="tabNavigation">
<li><a href="#topdownload" style="font:12px tahoma;">top</a></li>
  <li><a href="#featured" style="font:12px tahoma">more</a></li>
<li><a href="#toprated" style="font:12px tahoma">defult</a></li> 
<li><a href="#latest" style="font:12px tahoma;" >free</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: really **4min waiting to page load complete ??** isnt it too long ?? i would rather suggest you to decrease load lime to less than a minute at least

Comment: if you can answer my question i can do this :)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to load the images on the main tab on page load and then on the other tabs as they are displayed?

Comment: yes i want when i click on other tabs images on tab load .

Comment: @behzadn: the question is not clear, maybe [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the plugin you are using is very basic, and doesn't allow ajax requests.

One solution is to use the load method for externals html files (featured.htm, toprated.html...), but **I'm sure there is a better way using ajax request** to the server and a preload plugin.

#### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
   ...
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <!-- tabs -->
    <ul class="css-tabs">
       <li><a href="topdownload.htm">top</a></li>
       <li><a href="featured.htm">more</a></li>
       <li><a class="selected" href="toprated.htm">default</a></li>
       <li><a href="latest.htm">free</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- single pane. it is always visible -->
    <div class="css-panes">
      <div style="display:block">
        <!-- loaded content here -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### Jquery

Now we use ajax to load external pages using load method getting the `href` of the link element:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $("ul.css-tabs").tabs("div.css-panes > div", {
            effect: 'fade',
            onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {
            // get the pane to be opened
            var pane = this.getPanes().eq(i);
                // only load once. remove the if ( ... ){ } clause if
                // you want the page to be loaded every time
            if (pane.is(":empty")) {
                // load it with a page specified in the tab's href
                // attribute
                pane.load(this.getTabs().eq(i).attr("href"));
            }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### Demo

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax-noeffect.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by dynamically assign an image to the src property of the img tag you want to download on demand:

```
tabs = document.querySelector('#tabs a');
tabs[0].onclick = function(){anyImgTag.src = "images/someimage.jpeg"};
```